# What are the implications of using FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP?

Tags: android, android-intent

Could someone please explain what FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP do? The docs say

> If set, the activity will not be launched if it is already running at
>   the top of the history stack.

But that statement seems to be burying a great deal of meaning beneath it. For instance someone online mentioned that the top activity may not be the same as the activity at the top of the task stack. I have no idea what all of that means. Hence my greater question: **what are the implications of using FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP?**

Answer (score 0):

It means if the activity is already up and you call it again you wont replace it with a new one and you wont create another one (which sometimes happens and is evident when you hit back and you see the same activity up), instead you will pull that one up.

So say you have 3 activities: A -> b -> c. You are in C and you came to it through A and then B. If you call to A, from C with the SINGLE_TOP filter your stack will look like A, C, B - if you started to hit the back button, you would go to C, then B. I could be wrong but thats how i believe it is. You can also pass in the CLEAR filter with it to erase the back stack and techniquely be started back at A with no stack in back of it, you would back straight out to home. - please correct if im inaccurate.

Answer (score 0):

The following is an answer I read online. It is not a complete answer to the question you are asking, so I am *really* hoping someone else can add a lot more meat to it.

> If an instance of the activity already exists at the top of the
> current task, the system routes the intent to that instance through a
> call to its onNewIntent() method, rather than creating a new instance
> of the activity. The activity can be instantiated multiple times, each
> instance can belong to different tasks, and one task can have multiple
> instances (but only if the the activity at the top of the back stack
> is not an existing instance of the activity).
>
> For example, suppose a task's back stack consists of root activity A
> with activities B, C, and D on top (the stack is A-B-C-D; D is on
> top). An intent arrives for an activity of type D. If D has the
> default "standard" launch mode, a new instance of the class is
> launched and the stack becomes A-B-C-D-D. However, if D's launch mode
> is "singleTop", the existing instance of D is deliverd the intent
> through onNewIntent(), because it's at the top of the stack: the
> stack remains A-B-C-D. However, if an intent arrives for an activity
> of type B, then a new instance of B is added to the stack, even if its
> launch mode is "singleTop".

[Source](https://developer.android.com/guide/components/activities/tasks-and-back-stack)